# Dropbox API for Delphi, how do I send the data back to my Windows app?

Tags: delphi, oauth-2.0, dropbox

I am trying to download a file from my Dropbox.
The API requires a redirect url. My app does not have access to a web host. Do I need to include a TWebBrowser?
Without using a host, how do I send the auth query and the token back to my app?

I am using the Dropbox API for Delphi supplied by Clever Internet. 
I submit my request and my browser shows 
"Enter this code into MMPP to finish the process."
How do I send it back to my app?

```
procedure TDLoader.AssignCredentials(ADropbox: TDropboxManager);
begin
  ADropbox.ClientID := 'o2o.......4';
  ADropbox.ClientSecret := 'lwb..........2c';
  ADropbox.RedirectURL := 'http://localhost:55896'; // ??????
end;
procedure TDLoader.Download(const ASourceFile: string; ADestination: TStream);
var
  dbox: TDropboxManager;
begin
   Dbox := TDropboxManager.create;
   AssignCredentials(dbox);
   dbox.Download(ASourceFile, ADestination);
end;
```

I expected the file to d/l but instead, I got the "Enter this code into MMPP to finish the process."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the DropBox Api but from your description I suspect you use the [Device Code FLow](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/device-code/)

In this grant_type you start the flow calling a url (POST)(see docs) with scope and clientId and receive a verification_url, user_code and device_code; you must open the verification_url on browser and insert the user_code and complete the authentication.

When completed the authentication, on Delphi you must call (POST) another url (see docs) with device_code and clientId for getting the access_token.

Comment: Not helpful. This a Windows app and does not have a web interface. Trying to use the Dropbox API.

Comment: oAuth is based entirely on http!. To by-pass entirely the browser you can use the `client_credential` grant_type but in this case you acquire app permission not user permission.